# Remove a specific character from column value using pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I would like to remove some dots (`.`) from the column values but the tricky part is that I only want to remove the dots if they appear only once between numbers, but if there are two dots or three dots after each other, ignore them  **For example:**

[image]

my code:

```
pattern = r'\.(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\.'

df_glaccount_totaling = df_glaccount_totaling.withColumn('TOTALING', regexp_replace('TOTALING', pattern, ''))
```

out come is 6598.659899999  (with  on dot)
Desired output: 6598..659899999 ( two dots)

Comment: Can we see there code you’ve written in an attempt to meet the requirements you’ve described as a [mre]?

Comment: Can you also share more information about the specific data structure you’ve got in use?

Comment: [use udfs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html). If you have trouble, post your code here.

Comment: @esqew I did udpate my post. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your regex pattern to include positive lookahead/behind to match a digit i.e. a dot between two digits

```
regex = r'(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)'
df = df.withColumn('TOTALING', F.regexp_replace('TOTALING', regex, ''))
```

Result

```
df.show()
+--------------------+
|            TOTALING|
+--------------------+
|     6598..659899999|
|     6491..649199999|
|                8808|
|               C8808|
|               C8810|
|700000000..729999999|
+--------------------+
```